# Trying to run Flask app gives "Address already in use"

Tags: python, flask

I recently updated my app and tried to run it, and got the following error about "Address already in use".  What does this mean and how do I fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    app.run(host = os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'), port=int(os.getenv('PORT',8080)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 687, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 653, in inner
    fd=fd).serve_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 557, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 467, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 430, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Comment: It means there's another service's using that port (`8080` in this case).  Maybe because you forgot close another running Flask app and it's using `8080` port.

Comment: @KevinGuan but I've only deployed one flask app :/

Comment: address already in use means that the server couldnt be started, because another server runs on that port. Check if your program already runs, if it does so, terminate it. Also you can look at the active tcp servers using tcpview on windows systems.

Comment: @user119264: Well, you could use `nmap` or `netcat` to check which program is using that port. Here's another question and the accepted answer is using `netcat`, check it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port

Comment: change it to     app.run(host=os.getenv('IP',0.0.0.0'),port=int(os.getenv('PORT',5000)))

Comment: @Pradheep gives me the same error in Cloud9

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It means there's another service's using that port (`8080` in this case). Maybe because you forgot close another running Flask app and it's using `8080` port.

However, you could change the port you're using, for example change it to `4444` like this:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'), 
            port=int(os.getenv('PORT', 4444)))
```

But anyways, I think you'd like to know which program is using that part if it's not your program. You could use [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/) or [`netcat`](https://netcat.sourceforge.net/) GNU program to check it.

Here's the `netcat` way ([from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port)):

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep 8080
tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:8080  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  125004/nginx
```

When you got it, I'd suggest stop it manually (for example if it's `nginx` or other HTTP servers, then stop it via `service` command or `systemctl` if you're using systemd Linux)

You can also kill it via command `kill`:

```
kill <pid>
```

You can also kill it via `killall` or `pkill`, it use a process name instead of it's pid:

```
killall/pkill <process name>
```

Answer (score 22):

Try to kill all the other processes which are running on your server using this command

> sudo fuser -k xxxx/tcp

replace xxxx with your port name

Answer (score 22):

On OSX (12.1)

Run:

**sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep 5000**

```
ControlCe  1619        xxx   21u  IPv4 xxx      0t0    TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
ControlCe  1619        xxx   22u  IPv6 xxx      0t0    TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
```

If ControlCe is returned (Apple's Control Center) is running.  To turn it OFF go to:

Apple/System Preferences/Sharing/ and turn OFF AirPlay Receiver

Comment: Thank you for explaining the meaning of ControlCe on OSX.

Answer (score 14):

You can get the pid of all running processes having python keyword using the command:

> ps -fA | grep python

After getting the pid's use kill command as follows:

> kill -9 pid

After running above two commands now run the flask app, it will work fine

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the original question?

Answer (score 11):

You can simply use host and port parameter of run function to set another host and port .so that you can test your application.

```py
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.9',port=4455,debug=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue.

I listed all application running with the command

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

And there was another application using the same port.

After I stopped the other application, I could start my Flask application.

Answer (score 8):

This will kill all processes on port `8080`

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:"8080")
```

If you are using `Ctrl+Z` which just stops the process (pauses) instead of `Ctrl+C` to stop the process you may end up with an `open port`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but killing the current process didn't help as it would happen at runtime. I placed a `subprocess.run` with a bash script to kill it right before the `app.run` in my python and it worked.

```
#!/bin/bash

kill $(lsof -i:5001 -t)
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you use "ctrl+z" when flask app is running. When you run your flask app again in same terminal you get the error "OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use"

Solution:

```
fg
use "ctrl+c" this time to stop
```

[image]

When we use "ctrl+z" the process runs in background, we then bring it to the foreground using the "fg" and then use "ctrl+c" to stop it

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting terminal/shell or whatever platform you are using to run python. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

if none of the troubleshooting methods given work for you, you can just run the app on another port >> use that code in the server module :

```
app.run(debug=True, port=8001)
```

it will run the app on port 8001 instead of the default one (5000)

and *** do not forget to change the url address in the app.js file editing the port 5000 in the url to become 8001

ps : you can use other ports than 8001 also .. i just used it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

In my case no suggestion given here worked and rebooting was only solution.  This is not a complaint, just information for those not getting a pid. In every suggested solution here no pid was there for me to kill, though it was listening to the port. Closing and restarting terminal flask was launched from did not help. Logging out of Gnome did not work as it gave me forever spinning wheel after password entered. I ultimately rebooted and now commands given such as ss do provide a pid, so it wasn't a problem with the switches for my version of linux.