# How can I solve Python IDLE3 start problem?

Tags: python, python-idle

friends...
I've just installed IDLE3 package for Python (running Python 3.8)...
When I try to start it there is a message like this:

```
[ibmsys01@gustavo-ubuntu ~/zPDT]$ idle
** Invalid host:  ('192.168.0.17', 57676)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 1516, in main
    shell = flist.open_shell()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 331, in open_shell
    if not self.pyshell.begin():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 1049, in begin
    client = self.interp.start_subprocess()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 465, in start_subprocess
    self.rpcclt.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/rpc.py", line 544, in accept
    raise OSError
OSError
[ibmsys01@gustavo-ubuntu ~/zPDT]$
```

I haven't found any reference to this error. Has any of you seen it before? Can you please help get through it?
My environment is:

```
Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Python 3.8.5
IDLE3
```

An additional detail: invoking "idle" or "idle3" gives me the same error.
Can you please help me get through this?
Thank you and best regards.

Gustavo.

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457981/trying-to-run-flask-app-gives-address-already-in-use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 IDLE dies with "Invalid host"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839641/python3-idle-dies-with-invalid-host)